# Checking if a product ID has taxonomy term attached not working with has_term

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I am trying to figure out if a woocommerce product ID has an associated taxonomy term attached to it.

The below id **434** does indeed have an attached **rimless** term in the **material** taxonomy but the below returns **no**.

What am I doing wrong?

```
if( has_term( 'rimless', 'material', 434 ) ) 
{
    echo 'yep';
}
else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: are you absolutely sure that `material` is the internal name of the taxonomy and `rimless` is the slug of the term, and not just their human readable names? Have you tested with a term ID? How did you confirm that post 434 has that term?

Comment: 100% - `material` is the name of the taxonomy and `rimless` is the slug of the term. I have triple check these. Yes, I have also used the term ID aswell, no dice. I have confirmed that **434** has this term attached, by going into the product edit page and checking it is checked, and checking if the product shows in the count column of the taxonomy page.

Comment: and if you pass a term object and a post object instead? I'm assuming there is no `switch_to_blog` style code at play? `has_term` is a wrapper around `is_object_in_term` which returns an error object with a message rather than `false` on failure, have you tried that? Somewhere there's an assumption being made that is false. How did you confirm the IDs?

Comment: @KeithDonegan Where are you running the code - on what page and in what hook, if any? But you can try Tom's suggestion - try using [`is_object_in_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_object_in_term/) - and see what does the message says, if you get a `WP_Error` instance.